# Setting attribute for HtmlButton in Repeater throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the code below in the ItemDataBound event for a Repeater control:

```
HtmlButton btnLike = (HtmlButton)e.Item.FindControl("LikeButton");
var itemLiked = new LikesService().GetByPostIdUserId(pollQ.PostId, new Guid(Membership.GetUser(this.Context.User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey.ToString()));
if (itemLiked != null)
    btnLike.Attributes["class"] = "btn btn-primary btn-sm";
```

I debugged the code but couldn't find why this line throws NullReferenceException:

```
btnLike.Attributes["class"] = "btn btn-primary btn-sm";
```

I verified in the debugger that the object `itemLiked` is not null.

Here is the markup for the HTML button in the Repeater:

```html
<button type="button" id="LikeButton" value='<%#Eval("PollQuestionID") %>' class='<%#GetCSS(Eval("PollQuestionID")) %>'>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> <%#LikeText(Eval("PollQuestionID")) %>
</button>
```

Comment: @Michael I thought so. But I verified that the name "LikeButton" is the same as what is found in the aspx page.

Comment: Show the markup for your Repeater.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Please see the markup in the edited question. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FindControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) method can only find *server controls* — those that have the `runat="server"` attribute. Add this attribute to your `<button>`:

```
<button runat="server" type="button" id="LikeButton" ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Michael but the button calls on jQuery ajax event and putting runat="server will cause a postback which I don't want. What do u suggest I do at this point?

Comment: Since you specified `type="button"`, the button won't cause a postback even if it's a server control.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I'm so grateful.